# How to get Local Map Entries in Hazelcast

Tags: java, cloud, hazelcast

Is it possible to get list of Local Map Entries in Hazelcast ?

There is just a method that returns status of local entries,but not their actual values.

```
IMap map = Hazelcast.getMap("test");
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    map.put(i, i);
    map.get(i);
}
LocalMapStats stats = map.getLocalMapStats();
System.err.println(stats.getHits());
System.err.println(stats.getOwnedEntryCount());
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get localKeySet. Please look following:
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#localKeySet()